# Boost QVM Rotation with Quaternion

Tags: c++, boost, quaternions

I'm trying to rotate a point by using boost's qvm library, specifically with quaternions. While there is a lot of documentation [here](http://boostorg.github.io/qvm/), I haven't been able to find any working examples of actual code. I'm currently just trying to rotate the point (1, 0, 0) 90 degrees around the y-axis, which should result in 
the point (0, 0, -1). Below is my current working example:

```
const auto axis = boost::qvm::vec<double, 3>{{ 0.0, 1.0, 0.0}};
auto rotationAngle = (3.14159/2.0);

const boost::qvm::quat<double> q = boost::qvm::rot_quat(axis, rotationAngle);

const boost::qvm::vec<double, 3> rotateVec = q * (boost::qvm::conjugate(q) * boost::qvm::vec<double, 3>{{1.0, 0.0, 0.0}});
std::array<double, 3> rotatePos = {{boost::qvm::X(rotateVec), boost::qvm::Y(rotateVec), boost::qvm::Z(rotateVec)}};

std::array<double, 3> result = {{ 0.0, 0.0, -1.0 }};
EXPECT_EQ(result, rotatePos);
```

Here I am setting my axis of rotation and rotation angle for the quaternion, and then multiplying the vector (1, 0, 0) by the conjugate of the quaternion and then by the quaternion itself. I then get the xyz points of the new vector and compare it to the expected output.

The current output I'm getting is (1, 0, 0) instead of (0, 0, -1) and I'm unsure if this is because of incorrect use of the functions or a math error instead. I understand that order of operations is important and I am also a newbie with quaternions, so I'm unsure what exactly is to blame.

Do  I instead need to multiply the quaternion by another quaternion rather than a vector and if so how is this done instead?

I appreciate any help or examples to follow.

Comment: There are some unit test files in the `boost_1_62_0/libs/qvm/test` directory which may help.

Comment: Thank you for the help. I looked through some of the test code but I'm still unsure how to properly use the functions. The rot_quat_test.cpp uses matrices and I would like to just use vectors and quaternions if I am able.

Comment: I think one problem is that your initialization of rotateVec ends up being a complicated way of making the unit quaternion. I think you want q * v * q* (where q* is the conjugate of q) rather than q * q* * v.

Comment: @aDrow Have you found a solution in the meantime? I agree with user888379 that the equation should be q * v * q*, but that leads to an error: invalid operands to binary expression.

Answer (score 0):

Strangely enough, if you remove multiplication by the quaternion conjugate it returns the expected result.

```
const boost::qvm::vec<double, 3> rotateVec = q * (boost::qvm::conjugate(q) * boost::qvm::vec<double, 3>{{1.0, 0.0, 0.0}});
```

changed to

```
const boost::qvm::vec<double, 3> rotateVec = q * boost::qvm::vec<double, 3>{{1.0, 0.0, 0.0}};
```

Could it be the boost does conjugate multiplication internally?